# How to disappear logon screen in each time run Crystal Report using C# in another machine

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, crystal-reports-2010

I have a problem in showing report using Crystal Report. I don't have a problem in my local pc, but when i try to run my report in another machine (PC) crystal report always shows logon screen like this below :

[image: logon screen]

Based on screen shot above, the information only shows the server name, loginID and password, database was disable. So I can't show the data from report even I fill the correct loginID and password, because I can't fill database name (database fill box was disabled by default).

I develop this report using microsoft visual studio 2010, and I set the target framework = 3.5. For SQL Server, I used SQL Server 2014.

As for the other PC specs that I use to test this report is a windows server 2012 with SQL Server 2014.
I also have already install the CRRuntime_64bit_12_0_15 in this machine.

I used this code to show the report :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using CrystalDecisions;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace SGLCreditControlReport
{
public partial class FrmPreview : Form
{
    string BranchID, Department, Period1, Period2, AssetClass;
    string server, dbname, userdb, passdb;

    public FrmPreview(string branchID, string Department, string AssetClass, string Period1, string Period2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BranchID = branchID;
        this.Department = Department;
        this.Period1 = Period1;
        this.Period2 = Period2;
        this.AssetClass = AssetClass;

        server = Properties.Settings.Default.server;
        dbname = Properties.Settings.Default.dbname;
        userdb = Properties.Settings.Default.userid;
        passdb = Properties.Settings.Default.passid;
    }

    private void FrmPreview_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }

    private void FrmPreview_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExecuteReport(this.BranchID, this.Department, this.AssetClass , this.Period1, this.Period2);
    }

    private void ExecuteReport(string branchID, string department, string assetClass, string periodMonth, string periodYear)
    {
        string periodFix = periodYear + periodMonth;
        TableLogOnInfo tblLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        TableLogOnInfos tblLogOnInfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

        ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
        rptDoc.Load(@"rptAssetList.rpt");

        loadReport(tblLogOnInfo, tblLogOnInfos, conInfo, rptDoc, branchID, department, assetClass, periodMonth, periodYear);

    }

    private void loadReport(TableLogOnInfo tblLogOnInfo, TableLogOnInfos tblLogOnInfos, ConnectionInfo conInfo, ReportDocument rptDoc, string branchID, string department, string assetClass, string periodMonth, string periodYear)
    {
        conInfo.ServerName = server;
        conInfo.DatabaseName = dbname;
        conInfo.UserID = userdb;
        conInfo.Password = passdb;
        string periodFix = periodYear + periodMonth;
        string query;
        Tables tbls = rptDoc.Database.Tables;

        foreach (Table CrTable in tbls)
        {
            tblLogOnInfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            tblLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = conInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(tblLogOnInfo);
        }

        #region set null for empty string
        if (branchID == "")
            branchID = null;
        if (department == "")
            department = null;
        if (assetClass == "")
            assetClass = null;
        if (periodFix == "")
            periodFix = null;
        #endregion

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;

        //------ for passing parameter value ---------//
        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@Period", periodFix);
        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@BranchCD", branchID);
        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@AssetClass", assetClass);
        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@Department", department);
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
}
}
```

Please give references or suggestions how to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: are you doing rptdoc.SetDataSource before crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc?

Comment: no, i am not. is that mandatory ?

Comment: you are executing procedure with your query string variable somewhere as of me. So that Dataset you need to set as rptdoc.SetDataSource(ds). Otherwise how your data output bind to report?

Comment: Sorry, I have modified my code. I forgot to clear exec query. I have already connect my .rpt file data connection direct to server (another machine). Update the current data connection to server's (another machine) connection . And it works.. I don't know why it can be happened. But overall thank you for your response :)